# How to enable VideoView TouchListener Android?

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview, playback, ontouchlistener

I am implementing video player within that i want to play/pause video onTouch of VideoView.
Is it possible using video View only if yes then tell me the way . I don't want this using surfaceview so please tell me only using VideoView . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put your videoview in linearlayout and intialize it and use like below code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutLiveVideo;

    linearLayoutLiveVideo.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch entered");
         //your play pause code
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i have faces this issue and the solutions is:-

1-in your xml set the followin attribute to webview

android:clickable="true"

2- simply in your code set setOnClickListenerto the webview and it will work like charm:

```
 videoView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(CinemaDetailsActivity.this , FullScreenPlayerActivity.class);


            intent.putExtra("url" ,  getIntent().getStringExtra("url"));
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```